# PHP and Mongo - findOne() causes memory exhaustion

Tags: php, mongodb

My PHP memory_limit is 64M (which is pretty high to start with)

I have a MongoCollection::findOne() called in my PHP code where I "find one" by MongoId.
It works in most cases. However in some cases, it causes PHP to go over the memory_limit of 64M.

The data record in Mongo is at max, 3.5MB because Mongo does not allow more than 4MB.

When I run, memory_get_usage() before calling findOne(), its only about 4MB. So findOne() seems to have consumed the other 60MB+. Is this a memory leak or is there a design flaw in the way I store in Mongo?

My PHP Mongo driver is the latest 1.26

Comment: Did you supply anything to MongoCollection::findOne() ?

Comment: The code is like this:

`$cond = array('_id' => new MongoId('4e76e544546ba04617000000'));
$record = $objCollection->findOne($cond); // memory exhaustion in this line`

Comment: How about you try to pass in scaler value (string of the ID) instead of the object?

Comment: I tried `$cond = array('_id' => '4e76e544546ba04617000000');` - it did not even find the record.

Comment: it's not going to find that record as you have to specify the mongo id; it's not just a string. Secondly, what version are you at with Mongo? Please update the question with those items

Comment: "... because Mongo does not allow more than 4MB" - this is not true anymore. More recent versions of the db allow up to 16MB per document. Also, keep in mind that this refers to the binary data size; if the object is deseralized, it may grow in size considerably. Depending on implementation details, expect at least three times the data size as a RAM requirement.

Comment: Can you paste the error message you're getting?

Comment: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 68157440 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 71 bytes)

Thats the error message. Mongo's findOne() internally eats up all the memory in this case.

Comment: Can you maybe include some JSON for the record? I'm having trouble believing this is Mongo.

Comment: How many records do you have it that collection? Surprised nobody asked this question yet.

Comment: Did you get a final solution to your problem at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could post the exact code that you are running.  It is most likely your code, but there is a chance that it could be a bug with the Mongo PHP drivers.  The latest version of the drivers (1.2.9) seems to be a step backwards from previous versions.  I myself found a bug in the driver that causes php to segfault on connection timeouts :o  In a conversation that I had with a 10gen developer it was revealed to me that the php drivers are the least mature of all the languages, but I was told that they just hired a php developer so the drivers should be getting some love soon.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing that Mongo looks up by strict hashing, and that the lookup sequence for any given ID is limited, there is absolutely no way this could be Mongo's doing.

If you are using a MongoID then you should be *sure* that the ID is valid. Because a MongoID is the *resolved* hash for the given record.

This might be the problem. Or I might be entirely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know too much about your specific case; however, that has happened to me a number of times using mysql and cakephp. I've never used mongo with php though. Try the following:

A) Have you set up any indexes in your DB?
B) You can increase your memory limit through php.ini, mine is usually set around 256mb.
C) It could be the case that your associations have caused a bunch of objects to be created. I doubt your query is causing the 60mb to fill up, but rather some recursive chaos due to associations. Try unbinding associations before calling your query.
D) Turn off all associations and slowly work your way up.

I know mongo is supposed to eliminate the need for complex queries. Perhaps this is more of a language/library issue?

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try the `db.<your collection>.validate()` command on the respective collection from the shell.
Try a `db.<your collection>.reIndex()` call on the collection.
Try dropping all indexes and recreating them on that collection (even all collections; won't hurt anything).
Try `db.repairDatabase()` from the shell.

Also, from your PHP code, try the same criteria as a find() and see if you get memory corruption.